# IOS 7 & MSFT Exchange: Deleted email keeps re-appearing

Tags: ios, exchange-activesync

I have an iPhone 5 running IOS 7 that is connected to my company's MSFT Exchange server.  I get email without a problem, send without a problem and with 1 exception, actions taken via desktop Outlook replicate to my iPhone and vice versa.

Yesterday I received an email(small, no attachment) from someone that occasionally sends me email.  I deleted it on my phone and didn't have any problem.  About 45 minutes later it reappeared as an unread email.  When I open it, it says "The message has not been downloaded from the server".  It is deleted from Outlook and I emptied the trash folder.

This loop has been repeated a dozen times.  I reset the phone, turned off mail syncing to no avail.  My last resort is to delete the account and re-create it but I'd like to avoid that as it's a hassle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ended up having to delete the account and start from scratch